# passing a cookie from one sub domain to another sub domain

Tags: angular, cookies

I am creating a cookie 'sample' from a.website.com and after that, I am redirecting to b.website.com in the same window.I have set the cookie domain as top level 'website.com' and the path is '/'. When I open the chrome developer console of the website b.website.com, I did not see the cookie 'sample'. Can you suggest me what I am missing here? Is document.cookie different than a $cookie in Angular 1.x?

Raja K

Comment: Your request is similar to this other one- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3342140/8569576.

Comment: The same behavior applies for subdomains, unless they are set at the top level domain

Comment: Thanks. I am storing in the top level domain. It's not showing when I redirect

Comment: But the cookie in your description is being created while on a.website.com, not website.com. Hence, it's lost on site switch.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's the concern. what would be the solution. Is the approach is wrong?

Comment: Is document.cookie different than a $cookie in angular?

Comment: depending on the parameters you use in your setters/getters, both document.cookie and $cookie can be accessing/setting the same actual cookie.  The issue here isn't how you set or get the cookie, but from which website you set it.  The cookie needs to be created while on the top level domain, website.com.  Then a user's session in either a.website.com or b.website.com can get that cookie and read the values.